# Update HighCharts chart when AJAX Updates my data on my page

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Page where I have some Project Stats based on different Project Task Statuses.  On this page I use AJAX to update my Stat values as they change.

I am now trying to integrate a Highcharts bar chart/graph and I need to update it;s chart when my data changes.

There is a JSFiddle here showing the chart I am experimenting with now http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/9dr345og/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: document.getElementById('datatable')
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Project Stats'
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Total'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
          enabled: true,
          text: 'Project Stats'
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        }

    });


    // Button Click to Simulate my Data updating.  This increments the Completed Tasks bar by 1 on each click.
    $(".update").click(function() {
        var completedVal = $('#completed').text();
        ++completedVal
        $('#completed').text(completedVal)
    }); 

});
```

So this example is getting the data from a Table but I do not have to use this method, I could also set it with JavaScript if needed.

I just need to figure out how I can update all these values on the fly as my real live page updates my task stat values using AJAX so I would like this chart to update live as well.

Any help on how to make it update?  When my AJAX code is ran, I could call some JavaScript at that point if there is a function that rebuilds the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would drop the use of the table, especially since it looks like you are building it just for highcharts to consume it.  Instead return your data via AJAX as a Highcharts [series object](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series).  and then use the [Series.setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) method to update your plot.  This would be the *right* way to do it.

If you really want to use the table, you could query out the data and still use `setData` (this is what Highcharts is doing for you under the hood).  Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dr345og/2/).

```
$(".update").click(function() {
    var completedVal = $('#completed').text();
    ++completedVal;
    $('#completed').text(completedVal);
    // get y values
    var yValues = $.map($('#datatable tr td'),function(i){return parseFloat($(i).text());});
    // set data
    Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData(yValues);    
});
```